# Probability of rolling a below-average value at least 3 times in row

Tags: probability

If I roll a 20-sided dice five times what is the probability of rolling a below-average value at least 3 times in a row (consecutively)?

Comment: Below average is a 50-50 prospect, so you might as well rephrase it in terms of five coin tosses.

Comment: Do you mean the average of all the faces of the die (so 10.5), or the average of all rolls so far? The latter question is much more interesting.

Comment: The average of the faces - 10.5 indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events of rolling above ($A$) or below ($B$) the average have the same probability, hence it is enough to count how many strings like $BABBB$ have $3$ or more consecutive $B$s. There are $1+2+5=8$ strings made that way over $32$ total strings, so the wanted probability is one fourth.